# Finding the mean of bars in bar chart - d3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3 and am trying to draw mean line through all the bars in the bar chart but not quite able to achieve that. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #444;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data=[
 {"letter": "BU", "higher": .08,"lower": .05},
 {"letter": "AU", "higher": .05,"lower": .03},
 {"letter": "LA", "higher": .04,"lower": .02}

]

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeBands([0, width], 0);


var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom"); 

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.higher = +d.higher;
    d.lower = +d.lower;
  });


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  x2.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.higher; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.higher); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.higher-d.lower); });

var dataSum = d3.mean(data, function(d) { return (d.higher + d.lower); }); 


 var line = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d, i) { 
      return x(d.letter) + i; })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(dataSum/data.length); });
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);


</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

The proper code is here'http://jsbin.com/beyakumohi/1/edit?html' . The line should pass through center of each bars but it only happens for the 3rd bar and that too it do not cross it. Is there any mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3.mean will give you the mean value of the full array. Meaning, that in this case you will get the mean of:

```
data[0].higher + data[0].lower + data[1].higher + data[1].lower + data[2].higher + data[2].lower
```

In this case I would say it is more appropiate to edit your line function as following

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { 
        return x(d.letter); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y((d.higher + d.lower) / 2); });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I wonder why it is not crossing the 3rd bar my guess is it found the last point so the line ends but is there any way to make it reach right side of the 3rd bar. Please see this link 'http://jsbin.com/bicinirawa/edit?html'.

Comment: I see.. This is caused by the x scale function returning the left side of where the bars should start. Changing x funtion of the line function to 

    .x(function(d, i) { 
    return x(d.letter) + 0.5 * x.rangeBand(); })

should work

Comment: I mean the .interpolate("step-after"); should have a line crossing through the middle of 3rd bar

Comment: Ah I understand. How would you want this to behave when you have more than three bars? Start completely left, on all other bars go through the middle and then end all the way on the right at the final bar? In that case you would need to extend the function a bit: offset = i === 0 ? 0 : i === data.length-1 ? 1 : 0.5
        return x(d.letter) + offset * x.rangeBand();